# Cepstrum pitch detection

Tags: matlab, pitch, mfcc

I want to get pitch values using MFCC features in matlab using a function from this [link](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/Pitch.html):

```
[F0, T, C] = spPitchTrackCepstrum(y, 20000, 25.6, 10, 'hamming', 0);
```

But all numbers are positive (without unvoiced values).

Please, help me figure out how to do that properly.

Thanks

Comment: Please post more of your code, along with a link to the wave file you are using. And show an example of the results you are getting.

Comment: Here is .mat file which contains y vector for spPitchTrackCepstrum function [m5nw0000.pes file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74843400/m5nw000_.mat). The results are shown in [res.mat](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74843400/res.mat).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that pitch track can give to you information about voiced/Unvoiced frames ? One pitch track give you just information about the Pitch, this source code is a basic example that show you how get Pitch information between 50hz and 1K hz using cepstrum, if you need know if your frame is periodic or not or Voiced/Unvoiced do you need improve the code to have this feature !